# I am getting an error when i use imputer=imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3]) ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, valueerror

So i am Doing a preprocessing of data(Filling in Missing values with Mean values ) and following is the code

Note:It worked properly yesterday..It is giving me this error today

### I get the following error when i execute imputer=imputer(x[:,1:3])

```
    imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-1edbdae0a80f>", line 1, in <module>
    imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])

  File "C:\Users\super\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\imputation.py", line 158, in fit
    force_all_finite=False)

  File "C:\Users\super\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 527, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)

  File "C:\Users\super\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

---

Following is the Data

```
Country Age Salary  Purchased
France  44  72000   No
Spain   27  48000   Yes
Germany 30  54000   No
Spain   38  61000   No
Germany 40      Yes
France  35  58000   Yes
Spain       52000   No
France  48  79000   Yes
Germany 50  83000   No
France  37  67000   Yes
```

and here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

# Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])</code>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

SimpleImputer works similarly to the old Imputer; just import and use that instead. Imputer is not used anymore. Try this code:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean',verbose=0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])

X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

Comment: SimpleImputer works almost similar to the old Imputer, just import and use that, instead. Imputer is not used anymore. Try this one...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bring the full import of Sklearn to just impute a couple of columns. You can do that purely in Pandas itself using `fillna`.

```
import pandas as  pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Country': [
        'France',
        'Spain',
        'Germany',
        'Spain',
        'Germany',
        'France',
        'Spain',
        'France',
        'Germany',
        'France'
    ],
    'Age': [
        44,
        27,
        30,
        38,
        40,
        35,
        np.nan,
        48,
        50,
        37
    ],
    'Salary': [
        72000,
        48000,
        54000,
        61000,
        np.nan,
        58000,
        52000,
        79000,
        83000,
        67000
    ],
    'Purchased': [
        'No',
        'Yes',
        'No',
        'No',
        'Yes',
        'Yes',
        'No',
        'Yes',
        'No',
        'Yes'
    ]
})

df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(value=df['Age'].median())
df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].fillna(value=df['Salary'].median())
print(df)
```

and this will give you:

```
    Age  Country Purchased   Salary
0  44.0   France        No  72000.0
1  27.0    Spain       Yes  48000.0
2  30.0  Germany        No  54000.0
3  38.0    Spain        No  61000.0
4  40.0  Germany       Yes  61000.0
5  35.0   France       Yes  58000.0
6  38.0    Spain        No  52000.0
7  48.0   France       Yes  79000.0
8  50.0  Germany        No  83000.0
9  37.0   France       Yes  67000.0
```